# IBM Worklight - Include a JavaScript library on the server side

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm building a mobile application using IBM Worklight. In an adapter, I need to use some functionality which is provided by a third party JavaScript file. I want to know if it's possible to include such a file on the server? If not, what is the alternative?

Comment: There is a Feature Request opened at IBM to implement this feature. You can vote in it. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=43578

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no way to include an external JavaScript library in the Adapter code. Currently the only workaround is to copy the library code to the adapter.

Comment: :-| I feared as much! My adapter's going to bloat! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @shmulik is it possible now, include an external JavaScript library in the HttpAdapter code in mobilefirst

Answer (score 1):

In Worklight 6.0.0, IBM introduced Node.js adapters, touting "a huge selection of third-party modules extending connectivity and providing implementations of various common backend constructs".  That sounds like JS library support to me.  Details here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/a_preview_of_node_js_adapters_in_worklight_6_0_0?lang=en

Comment: It was unavailable on version 6.1 and 6.2. Source: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/a_preview_of_node_js_adapters_in_worklight_6_0_0?lang=en