# include JavaScript library on the server side in mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

is it possible now, include an external JavaScript library in the HttpAdapter code in MobileFirst. If not, what is the alternative?

I have seen this type of questions,but that was worklight older version and impossible .. [IBM Worklight - Include a JavaScript library on the server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399528/ibm-worklight-include-a-javascript-library-on-the-server-side)

MobileFirst: version 7.1.0.00-20151114-1616

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to include external JS *files* in adapters. What you can do, is to include the JS *source* in the existing *-impl.js file.

Comment: is it  possible to further ? please update your answer

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: now ,It is not possible to include external JS files in adapters . if MobileFirst offer to include js files in adapters in future ..please update your answer ,is possible for you .

Comment: Do you mean that the only way would be to copy and paste the library code inside the adapter-impl file?

Comment: As there is only 1 permitted JS file, you can only put code in this single file.